# mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build fails to locate Graalvm installation directory

Tags: environment-variables

I hope this isn't a simple error pertaining to a misuse of environment variables!

[EDIT: YEP that's what happened. I think I might just delete this whole question so as not to clog the topic for other Gluon/Graavlm questions.]

The [Gluon documentation for creating an Android build](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_android) has us execute the following command:

```
mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build
```

I am executing this on my Ubuntu 20.04 system, from the downloaded "HelloFX" project that is referenced in the documentation.

```
phil@UbuntuDesktop:~/Projects/metronome/gluon-samples-master/HelloFX$ echo $GRAALVM_HOME
/usr/lib/graalvm-svn-linux-gluon-21.2.0-dev
phil@UbuntuDesktop:~/Projects/metronome/gluon-samples-master/HelloFX$ sudo mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build
[sudo] password for phil: 
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< com.gluonhq.samples:hellofx >---------------------
[INFO] Building HelloFX 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.5:build (default-cli) @ hellofx ---
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< com.gluonhq.samples:hellofx >---------------------
[INFO] Building HelloFX 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.5:compile (default-cli) > process-classes @ hellofx >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ hellofx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ hellofx ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.5:compile (default-cli) < process-classes @ hellofx <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.5:compile (default-cli) @ hellofx ---
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: GraalVM installation directory not found. Either set GRAALVM_HOME as an environment variable or set graalvmHome in gluonfx-plugin configuration
    at com.gluonhq.NativeBaseMojo.createSubstrateDispatcher(NativeBaseMojo.java:147)
    at com.gluonhq.NativeCompileMojo.execute(NativeCompileMojo.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

There is more to the console output. I will include this if requested.

I am assuming the key line here is:

> org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: GraalVM installation
> directory not found. Either set GRAALVM_HOME as an environment
> variable or set graalvmHome in gluonfx-plugin configuration

Following is a listing of the files that are located in the folder referenced by GRAALVM_HOME. These were unpacked from the version of Graalvm listed in the Gluon documentation.

```
phil@UbuntuDesktop:~/Projects/metronome/gluon-samples-master/HelloFX$ cd $GRAALVM_HOME
phil@UbuntuDesktop:/usr/lib/graalvm-svn-linux-gluon-21.2.0-dev$ ls -al
total 388
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root   4096 Sep 13 16:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 135 root root  12288 Sep 13 19:04 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  29628 Sep 13 16:43 3rd_party_license_llvm-toolchain.txt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Sep 13 16:43 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root   4096 Sep 13 16:43 conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   2316 Sep 13 16:43 GRAALVM-README.md
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 Sep 13 16:43 include
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Sep 13 16:43 jmods
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 Sep 13 16:43 languages
drwxr-xr-x  72 root root   4096 Sep 13 16:43 legal
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root   4096 Sep 13 16:43 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  21035 Sep 13 16:43 LICENSE_NATIVEIMAGE.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  27235 Sep 13 16:43 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   2766 Sep 13 16:43 release
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 257599 Sep 13 16:43 THIRD_PARTY_LICENSE.txt
```

What might be going wrong? Maybe the environment variable is being over-ridden by "graalvmHome in gluonfx-plugin configuration"? Doesn't that refer to the pom.xlm for the project? I don't see anything there or in the related maven profile for android.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gluonfx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                 <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                 <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

From the profiles:

```
    <profile>
        <id>android</id>
        <properties>
            <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

There may be more questions down the road on this process. I'm concerned that the documentation refers to the requirement for Android "extras" for m2Repositories for Android and Google to be installed, but my recently installed Android Studio does not offer these in the SDK Manager, SDK Tools as far as I can tell.

Comment: Why do you use/need `sudo`? It is possible that your user `$GRAALVM_HOME` variable is not defined then.

Comment: Ah -- the environment variable is stored with the user profile not the superuser profile. It WAS about a misuse/misunderstanding about environment variables. Thank you. I think I will answer this with your info and remove the gluon and other tags so as not to needlessly bring others to it. (Maybe I'll just delete the post altogether.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer that was spotted by @Jose Perdida: use of `sudo` took us out of the user environment where the environment variables were declared.

Answer (score 0):

Download => https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/tag/vm-22.1.0
and create new environment variable in your system name is  GRAALVM_HOME and path ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).